# Exchange ErrorInvalidClientAccessTokenRequest

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices

I built an Outlook Add-in and it uses a token to download email attachments from the Exchange server.
On my O365 developer account, it successfully retrieves the token. 
The Add-in has been deployed to the client's Outlook but when they try to retrieve the token, this is the response message:

MessageText:"The token for this extension could not be retrieved.
"ResponseClass:"Error"
ResponseCode:"ErrorInvalidClientAccessTokenRequest"
Token:null
__type:"GetClientAccessTokenResponseMessage:#Exchange"

The code is exactly the same and so is the request. Is there any clues I could look into to figure out what about their environment would cause this to fail?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy it on a OnPrem server ? if so I would suggest https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stephen_griffin/2013/10/01/mail-apps-and-oauth-aka-your-mail-app-is-busted/

Comment: @Michael Yao , Did you found out the work around on this , I know its too old question for you , I am stucked exactly there.

Comment: also raised the same question because of no solution here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061449/microsoft-web-addins-office-context-mailbox-getcallbacktokenasync-returns-resp   Please answer the question if you have the solution over my queries

Answer (score 0):

The ErrorInvalidClientAccessTokenRequest field is applicable for clients that target Exchange Online and versions of Exchange starting with Exchange Server 2013.