# Microsoft Web Addins "Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync" returns response "Failed" on my Exchange 2016 but works in office 365 online

Tags: oauth, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

We have exchange 2016 sever which we have updated to CU-12 recently because we thought it might be the sever update thing, but now it seems it don't works with update too

I am simply using Rest API with the help of passing token to get some fields from the current mail using Addin.

But It throws an response "failed" every time when the function "Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync" is called.

Code:

```
 1 Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({isRest: true, "asyncContext" : this.__archiveComponent}, function(result){
 2 if (result.status === "succeeded") {
 3    let accessToken = result.value;
 4    result.asyncContext.getMultiValueExtendedProperty(accessToken,data[0]);
 5 } else {
 6     var err = result.name;
 7     console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
 8   }
 9 });
```

Error:in browser console the JSON response in details is:

```
{"Header":{"ServerVersionInfo":{"MajorVersion":15,
"MinorVersion":1,
"MajorBuildNumber":1713,
"MinorBuildNumber":5,
"Version":"V2017_07_11"
}},

"Body":{"ResponseMessages":{
"Items":[{"__type":"GetClientAccessTokenResponseMessage:#Exchange",
"MessageText":"The token for this extension could not be retrieved.",
"ResponseCode":"ErrorInvalidClientAccessTokenRequest",
"ResponseClass":"Error",
"Token":null}]
}}}
```

Note: This works fine in Office 365 online . I deployed the same on a OnPrem server
Exchange 2016 CU-12 update.

Hope should get some detailed explanation if anyone has fixed the same. I feel that there must be some configuration ,but need a guidance.

Some doubts which i have is

1. Does Rest Api only works with office online and not on OnPrem exchange server?
2. Or is it compulsory to have exchange online to get this work with onPrem Exchange server using HYBRID?

If Yes then if we build an addin with rest API and customer dont have office online what would be the way to get this work on customer onPrem exchange server.

More Info: I also See the similar question like this [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404323/exchange-errorinvalidclientaccesstokenrequest) but there is no relevant answer or suggession i see which clears my above questions.

Comment: We have seen this happen for Missing Signing Certificates. But What would really help is if you can grab the Exchange.log and look for the error you are seeing (The token for this extension could not be retrieved) And see if Exchange Logging has any additional information related to this error? If you were connecting through a Win32 Desktop Client the logs should be at: 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Logging\Ews, if on OWA they should be somewhere in: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Logging\OWA (exact paths will vary slightly)

Comment: I had look inside the logs and as you explained about the signing certificates, thats true. the anformations say "Microsoft.Exchange.Security.OAuth.OAuth Token RequestFailedException: Missing signing certificate. at Microsoft.Exchange.Security.OAuth.Token Issuer Base"

Comment: Can you suggest us some appropriate steps how to overcome this ? Bit new in server configuration here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments above, if you are hitting the Missing Signing Certificate issue, it could be because the Admin Server never created a new one. These steps may solve the issue.

1)  Create new self-signed certificate using [New-ExchangeCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/encryption-and-certificates/new-exchangecertificate?view=exchange-ps) cmdlet

2)  Modify the authorization configuration using [Set-AuthConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/organization/set-authconfig?view=exchange-ps) cmdlet to set thumbprint and publish the certificate created in step #1

Comment: Just a doubt: is it really compulsory to hybrid the exchange server to get start with OAuth?

Comment: Using OAuth in general and using the rest token from addins has different requirement. If your scenario is purely about getting REST token from addin and calling a REST API, then no, hybrid should not be required.  Also keep in mind that no all REST API's are supported on-premise.

Comment: @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT I am having a similar problem. When making request, do you need to have a on premise exchange server or can it work with any email. I made a new email, and I am receiving the same error code/message