# OfficeJs getUserIdentityTokenAsync failed to generate the token

Tags: exchange-server, office-js, outlook-web-addins

One of our customers faced an issue while using our Add-in for Microsoft Office.
When we call getUserIdentityTokenAsync it fails with an error

`{"value":null,"status":"failed","error":{"name":"InternalServerError","message":"The Exchange server returned an error. Please look at the diagnostics object for more information.","code":9042},"diagnostics":{"ErrorText":"The token for this extension could not be retrieved."}}`

It happened on Microsoft Exchange 2016 on perm.
In dev console, I found the following API call

`/owa/service.svc?action=GetClientAccessToken&EP=1&ID=-23&AC=1`

with the following request header

```
"name": "X-OWA-ActionName", 
"value": "Ext_GetUserIdentityToken"
```

and these headers in the response

```
{
    "name": "X-OWA-Version",
    "value": "15.1.1847.7"
},
{
    "name": "X-OWA-OWSVersion",
    "value": "V2017_08_18"
},
{
    "name": "X-OWA-DiagnosticsInfo",
    "value": "29;12;3"
},
{
    "name": "X-OWA-Error",
    "value": "Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.ErrorInvalidClientAccessTokenRequestException"
},
```

I believe it is customer's Exchange misconfiguration but could someone help me to understand what exactly not configured on Exhcange side?

Could it be a proxy configuration or something?
There is an X-OWA-CorrelationId response header, where I can find any information with that code?

many thanks.

Comment: One cause of this error is an expired certificate on the Exchange server hosting the user's mailbox, which is issuing the token. For more info on that issue, please see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061449/microsoft-web-addins-office-context-mailbox-getcallbacktokenasync-returns-resp

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it and come back.